# Simple dojo.query over xml document fails in IE

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax, internet-explorer, dojo

I have a very simple `dojo.query` over an xml document that is working in FireFox and Chrome, but failing in IE.  In IE this line gives the error `'undefined' is null or not an object`.

```js
var result = dojo.query("list > country", response);
```

The error in dojo happens in *eval code*, in the following function.  The line number is 791.

```js
// get an array of child *elements*, skipping text and comment nodes
var _childElements = function(filterFunc){
    filterFunc = filterFunc||yesman;
    return function(root, ret, bag){
        // get an array of child elements, skipping text and comment nodes
        var te, x = 0, tret = root[childNodesName];
        // THE ERROR HAPPENS HERE.  tret is 'undefined'
        while(te = tret[x++]){
            if(
                _simpleNodeTest(te) &&
                (!bag || _isUnique(te, bag)) &&
                (filterFunc(te, x))
            ){
                ret.push(te);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    };
};
```

I have confirmed (via IE Developer Tools) that the response is valid, and is set to an instance of `IXMLDOMDocument2`, with the appropriate child nodes.  The response provided by the `dojo.xhrGet` method, where I have `handleAs: "xml"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<countries>
 <list>
   <country>
    <code>1</code>
    <name>UNITED STATES</name>
   </country>
   <country>
    <code>2</code>
    <name>UNITED KINGDOM</name>
   </country>
   <!-- Snip -->
  </list>
</countries>
```

The `dojo.query` is the first attempt to access the `result` variable.  Is this a known issue?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: `In IE this line gives the error`, can you locate what line it is? i dont have dojo so i cant check it out

Comment: @david Let me switch to the development release and check.

Comment: @david See the update to the question.

Comment: is see looks like as you may already know `root[childNodesName]` is an issue with IE, sorry i cant help, eather wait and see who else responces or do a search relating to IE `root[childNodesName]` undefined

Comment: check it out and maybe file a bug http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11378, good luck with it

Comment: What version of Dojo are you using? This line of code is different in my 1.7 version (`tret = root.children ||  root.childNodes`) so perhaps it was a bugfix?

Comment: @missingno 1.6.1, which I thought was the current release version?

Comment: 1.7 [just came out](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/)! Woot \o\ |o| /o/

Comment: @missingno Would you care to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just confirmed that you have come across [a dojo bug](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/12488). You can fix it by upgrading to 1.7 or you can try just [applying that patch](http://trac.dojotoolkit.org/changeset/25510/dojopatching) changing the ocurrences of

```
root[childNodesName]
```

to

```
root.children || root.childNodes
```

in the dojo/selector/acme.js file